# MySQL returning lowest zip code

Tags: mysql, distinct-values

Got this SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(LocCity), LocZipCode FROM exp_course_events order by LocCity
```

and this data:

```
INSERT INTO `exp_course_events` (`LocCity`, `LocZipCode`) VALUES 
  ('Aguadilla', '00602'), ('Akron', '44300'),('Akron', '44333'),
  ('Albany', '12205'),    ('Albuquerque', '87102'),
  ('Albuquerque', '87109'), ('Austin', '78741'),
  ('Austin', '78753'), ('Austin', '78757'),
  ('Bend', '97701'), ('San Antonio', '78200'),
  ('San Antonio', '78201'),
  ....
  ('San Antonio', '78207');
```

Need to return only one value for LocZipCode for each LocCity, prefereable the lowest number LocZipCode 
for that LocCity.

This is results I'd like:

```
Aguadilla, 00602
Akron, 44300
Albany, 12205
Albuquerque, 87102
Austin, 78741
Bend, 97701
San Antonio, 78200
San Diego, 92108
San Francisco, 94111
San Juan, 00926
Santa Clara (San Jose), 95054
Springdale, 72762
Springfield, 62703
St. Louis. 63105
Visalia, 993291
Waco, 76705
Warwick, 02886
Waukesha, 53186
West Chester, 45069
West Des Moines, 50300
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT LocCity, MIN(LocZipCode) 
FROM exp_course_events 
GROUP BY LocCity
ORDER BY LocCity
```

Read about the [GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) clause here.

Comment: +1 For group by link. Note that the `order by` clause is not strictly needed in MySQL (although it does look nice), because the DB already orders the output of a `group by` in ascending order.

Answer (score 1):

```
select LocCity, min(LocZipCode)
from exp_course_events
group by LocCity
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple `GROUP BY` with a `MIN()` aggregate will do it.  Just be sure to alias the `MIN()` column with a name (like `AS LocZipCode`) so you can fetch it more easily application-side.

```
SELECT LocCity, MIN(LocZipCode) AS LocZipCode FROM exp_course_events GROUP BY LocCity;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT LocCity
    , MIN(LocZipCode)
FROM exp_course_events
GROUP by LocCity
order by LocCity
```